# iOS - Inapp purchase - handling crash

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I successfully integrated inapp purchase in my application. But I left with a doubt and searching on how to handle that situateion.
When user initiates inapp purchase, provides his authentication details. But due to some reason the app crashed before I handled finishedTransaction method and unlock the features in the app. 
Next time when the app is started, how will I know whether the purchase is successful or not?

Comment: Provide some code, there shouldnt be a crash

Comment: @Oritm - My code is not crashing. Only for precautionary measure, i want to handle that situation as well in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `finishTransaction` deletes the transaction from `paymentsQueue`. So if the crash occures **before** that, the payment **will stay at the queue**, and next time users launches the app, he will be asked to enter his password, and you'll be able to proceed the purchase again.

But if the crash occures after `finishTransaction` call,right before you have provided content, user will notice thta dontent is not provided, so he will be able to press the **restore** button.Or you could male a flag yourself after **finishTransaction** and check if you provided what you should had provided.

Comment: My question about crash is before "finishTransaction" being called.

Comment: The, eveything is ok,as i answered in the first part of my question.

Comment: Let me explain more: User entered the app store credentials, apple might have processed the payment and deducted money from credit card. When apple sends the response of successful payment and before calling the "finishTransaction", the app got crashed. Money is deducted, but i didn't handle the finishTransaction and unlocked the resources.... how to deal with it?

Comment: You payment is still in paymentqueue,and it will ask user to enter his credentials,no?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can.

But if the user has purchased, and apple received the payment, the user can always restore his purchase. When you press the pay button (or what you programmed)It will say: You already purchase this item, do you want to restore this purchase?

If restored, the finishedTransaction will then be called.

You dont have to pay again.